# How to enable html select post back apsx page when selection changed?

Tags: asp.net, autopostback, htmlcontrols

With asp.NET control dropdownlist, there is a property AutoPostBack, if it is set "True", the whole page will be posted back.

If the aspx page include a html element "select" like:

```
<select id="list" name="list" runat="server"
    DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="ID" ></select>
```

and it data is filled by code-behind.

Question is: how to allow this Select have AutoPostBack function too?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why don't you want to use the DropDownList .NET control?

Comment: Can't speak for the OP, but I can give you a couple of general reasons. ASPX controls are proprietary (meaning they are a separate concept to learn unto themselves) and mask the rendered HTML. In some cases they render asinine styling (especially inline) or make it hard to add semantic attributes. So, someone coming from HTML design or HTML5 but having to work on a WebForms project would probably prefer to avoid the ASPX proprietary controls.

Answer (score 0):

The DropDownList approach adds a __doPostBack('selectelementname', 'commandname'); call to the onchange event.  When you change the value, this then proceeds to post back to the server, and then the ASP.NET control processes the postback data in LoadPostData method.

HTH.

Comment: okay, thanks. I did like this: <select  id="dd" name="dd" runat="server" onchange="javascript:__doPostBack('dd', '')"></select>. 
then got error said "Object Expected..."

Comment: Huh, interesting... the HtmlSelect control does support loading posted data to the server...  run the app and right-click in the browser, select view source, and find the HTML element definition.  Make sure the ID and name properties are actually dd; if it is doing something with the name as in ct100$body$dd something like that, you have to use that value instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can't apply Auto post back property for html select control.To invoke function writen inside c# code page(serverside),you need to use webservice. You can call javascript function(client side) on 'onchange' event of html select control.